# How to suspend Oozie coordinator if a coordinator action fails?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

In my use case output of a coordinator action is used by next iteration, so if one of them fails, unfinished/corrupted data is fed into next coordinator action.

Is there any way to suspend an Oozie coordinator if one of the workflow steps in a coordinator action fails?

For example instead of:

```
<action name="Delete_TMP_Files">
  <fs>
    <delete path='${outputPath}*'/>
  </fs>
  <ok to="End"/>
  <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
```

Can we do something like:

```
<action name="Delete_TMP_Files">
  <fs>
    <delete path='${outputPath}*'/>
  </fs>
  <ok to="End"/>
  <error to="Suspend"/>
</action>
```

so the error can be diagnosed before its output gets overwritten by next coordinator action?

PS: fs>delete is not the actual use case here, just an example.

Comment: If your "Suspend" action was a Shell action with an infinite loop -- e.g. `while [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] ; do sleep 1h ; done` -- then it would effectively make your Workflow hang; and with a Coordinator `<concurrency>1</concurrency>` option, that would also make the Coordinator hang. But that would not catch the case where the Workflow is killed while running.

Comment: You could also create a kind of `_SUCCESS` semaphore, just like Pig or Spark do, in the final Action of your Workflow -- and have the Coordinator wait for that semaphore with a `<dataset>` clause; then the first Action of next Workflow run would delete it, and so on. But that "dataset" clause sounds complicated, a lot more that this post implies https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not suspend a coordinator based on the failure of a workflow (from coordinator action).

If the output of the workflow have a certain pattern then you can use that and check it at the start of the workflow.

Otherwise, you can always `touch` a file as a last action in the workflow whenever it is successful and in case of failure, delete (if same file, not date based). Use the same file as the first check in your workflow and proceed accordingly. Initially, you might need to create the file manually.

You can use the email action in case of failure and get notified.

This is just a work around.